# Html table - adaptive size

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollbar

I have a container div, with a certain size. Let's say that it is in the center of the page, taking up 70% of page width and height. I'd like to have a table with following properties:

- The table always takes 100% of container width.
- When there are few rows, the height of the table is as small as required by table rows.
- When there are more rows than fit into the container div, the table body becomes scrollable so that the table doesn't extend over the container size.

So far I've figured out how to make the table body scrollable. But here's my problem: If I set the table size to 100%, it only takes minimal space (only shows one row) even if there are many rows. With fixed size it works, but that's not a viable solution in this case. How could I make the table to scroll only when there are too many rows, and otherwise show all rows? Also, how would I scale headers in that case? Headers must be scaled differently depending on if a scrollbar is shown or not, because only body is scrollable.

EDIT: Here's my css for the table:

```
.report {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.report tbody tr {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.report thead tr{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: calc( 100% - 2vw);
}

.report tbody {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT2: Would it be possible to extend the last table cell to the blank space? So in the following scheme, expand the header3 to the space marked with X?

```
---------------------------------------
| header1  |  header2  | header3  | X |
---------------------------------------
| content1 | content2  | content3 | ^ |
---------------------------------------
| content1 | content2  | content3 || ||
---------------------------------------
| content1 | content2  | content3 | v |
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can actually see what you're trying to do!

Comment: Do you want table header fixed and body only scrollable right?

Comment: Yes, only the body should be scrollable.